# Execute a module immediately after calling import in ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm working on something on NodeJS and I'm using the `import` keyword from the ES6 syntax.. and I want to execute immediately after calling it. I searched for similar thoughts to do that but nothing was helpful enough.

What I want to do is basically transform the following code from the CommonJS into the ES6.

```
// In CommonJS:
var birds = require('./birds')()

// In ES6:
import birds from './birds'()
```

I can do that using the `const` keyword:

```
import birds from './birds'
const SomethingButNotBirds = birds()
```

But, I really wanna know if there's a better way to do it.

I really appreciate your help guys!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ES6 import statement has a declarative syntax and does not give you room to execute functions just as you'd do with `require()()`.

The code you have below is the only valid way of doing it.

```
import birds from './birds'
const SomethingButNotBirds = birds()
```

Comment: Okay. it's fine actually to do so. But the only problem here is I won't be able to use the same variable I want.

Do you think there's a better technic than:
`import birdsRoutes from './birds'`
`const birds = birdsRoutes()`.

or something like:
`const birds = require('./birds')()`.

Think of it that you have a +15 routes under each other. What would you do?

Comment: You could try `import * as bd from './birds';` and use `const bird = bd.bird()` 
However, you should know that this has performance issues importing * imports all functions in birds

Comment: **Looks possible!** I'll search for the `* as bd` syntax and I'll try it soon. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @YahiaRefaiea Alright. You can upvote my answer if it has somewhat helped you.

Comment: Sorry buddy. I really did that. but, I have less than 15 reputation. so it didn't work

Comment: @FortuneEkeruo Your point about performance is not quite right. Both forms load the whole file, it just varies in how good your bundler is at telling if a given function is actually used or not. Plenty of them support the namespace version too safely.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks for pointing that out buddy, I'll research more about it. Thanks once again @loganfsmyth